# Using the enum from class template's scope without specyfing template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enums, class-template

Having such a code:

```
template<size_t lines, size_t line_size> class Lcd
{
public:
   enum class Interface : uint8_t
   {
      _8_BIT = 0x30,
      _4_BIT = 0x20,
   };

   Lcd(Interface interface);
   // some other stuff
}
```

```
int main()
{
   Lcd<4, 20> lcd(Lcd<4, 20>::Interface::_4_BIT);
}
```

Could I change the code so that it would be possible to call the `Interface` enum without using the `<4, 20>` specifier as the enum is universal?

I would prefer for the enum to be inside the `Lcd` scope and I need the `lines` and `line_size` to be passed through template parameters. Is it fine to just leave it as it is?

Comment: It's possible for a specialization to not have that enum.

Comment: If you want to access something inside the template class you need to specify the template parameters. Maybe you could put the template class in a namespace, and place the enums in the namespace outside the class if they are intended to be shared by all template instatiations.

Comment: @cigien I should have made an indication that it is not my entire code.
Anyway thanks to you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could I change the code so that it would be possible to call the
> `Interface` enum without using the `<4, 20>` specifier as the enum is
> universal?

**No**, it is not possible. As *@super* already mentioned in the comments, in order to access something inside the template class, you need to specify the template parameters.

The best you can do is to put the template class in a namespace and place the `Interface` enums in the namespace outside the class, by which you can avoid the `<4, 20>`.

```
namespace TClasses
{
   enum class Interface : uint8_t {
      _8_BIT = 0x30,
      _4_BIT = 0x20,
   };

   template<std::size_t lines, std::size_t line_size> class Lcd
   {
     // ...code
   };
}
```

Now

```
TClasses::Lcd<4, 20> lcd{ TClasses::Interface::_4_BIT };
```

---

> I would prefer for the enum to be inside the `Lcd` scope and I need the
> `lines` and `line_size` to be passed through template parameters.

Then there is no other option to use as you have shown. However, if you insist to have less typing, I would suggest [an alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) for the  `Interface` outside the class scope.

```
// type alias for the Interface
template<size_t lines, size_t line_size>
using LcdEnum = typename Lcd<lines, line_size>::Interface;
```

this will let you write

```
Lcd<4, 20> lcd{ LcdEnum<4, 20>::_4_BIT };
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In addition if you provide [a class template deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for `Lcd`, you need to mention the `<4, 20>` only once (i.e. `Lcd lcd{ LcdEnum<4u, 20u>::_4_BIT }`). That part I leave it you.